# how to combine Jasny Bootstrap with ResponsiveFileManager 9.8.1

Tags: image-upload, file-manager, jasny-bootstrap

I wanna to combine  `Jasny Bootstrap` file upload with `Responsive File Manager 9.8.1`. for example when I use `Jasny Bootstrap File Upload` and click on the select file, show me `Responsive File Manager 9.8` in pop-up and when I select image, the image thumbnail shown in `Jasny Image upload widgets`.

[Jasny Image upload widgets](http://jasny.github.io/bootstrap/javascript/#fileinput)

[Responsive File Manager 9.8.1](http://www.responsivefilemanager.com/)

Answer (score 0):

It's very simple.
You must change  in 
and after open the link of filemanager passing fieldID=your id on url.

See the example in demo page on Select All Files: 
http://responsivefilemanager.com/demo.php